# Number of occurrences of pair of row elements from the same column

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have the following data (a sample from some 20000 rows)

```
    Date        Time                Transaction Item            Year    Month   Day Weekday Hour
0   2016-10-30  2018-10-25 09:58:11 1           Bread           2016    10      30  6       9
1   2016-10-30  2018-10-25 10:05:34 2           Scandinavian    2016    10      30  6       10
2   2016-10-30  2018-10-25 10:05:34 2           Scandinavian    2016    10      30  6       10
3   2016-10-30  2018-10-25 10:07:57 3           Hot chocolate   2016    10      30  6       10
4   2016-10-30  2018-10-25 10:07:57 3           Jam             2016    10      30  6       10
5   2016-10-30  2018-10-25 10:07:57 3           Cookies         2016    10      30  6       10
6   2016-10-30  2018-10-25 10:08:41 4           Muffin          2016    10      30  6       10
7   2016-10-30  2018-10-25 10:13:03 5           Coffee          2016    10      30  6       10
8   2016-10-30  2018-10-25 10:13:03 5           Pastry          2016    10      30  6       10
9   2016-10-30  2018-10-25 10:13:03 5           Bread           2016    10      30  6       10
```

I'm trying to analyze the two most frequently bought items. Like Bread and Jam or Coffee and Bread. I have the transaction ids so it is based on that we can analyze this property. I want to find the complete number of occurrences of all possible pairs according to the transaction id. How do I achieve this?

Comment: So market basket analysis? MLXtend has [apriori and association rules](http://rasbt.github.io/mlxtend/api_subpackages/mlxtend.frequent_patterns/). See the usage examples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do a cross join on the transaction ID and then group by the different pairs deduplicating the pairs ordering alphabetically.

```
cross = df.merge(df, on='Transaction')
cross[cross['Item_x']>cross['Item_y']].groupby(['Item_x','Item_y']).size()
```

Comment: Thank you! Exactly what I needed.